# No se puede cargar el archivo DLL HRESULT: 0x8007007E

Tags: c#

estoy adentrandome en el mundo de la programación en C#, sin embargo, no puedo compilar ningún código, el erro que sale es este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

ya intenté descargar el archivo DLL que dice faltar en system32 y no era el problema

Comment: Intenta moviendo la solucion a una carpeta mas corta, create una en el c:\repos y copia alli el .sln y los proyectos, luego abre y compila con el VS

Comment: estas referenciando alguna libreria de terceros? quizas alguna libreria de office

Comment: Verifica que tengas un valor en el directorio de salida, esto lo puedes comprobar en la pestaña **Compilación** en el campo **Ruta de Acceso de Salida** en las propiedades de tu proyecto tal y como lo mencionan en esta liga: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/9b864b5a-b669-438d-b6b6-851abc2eb0f0/problema-en-la-depuracin?forum=vsgenerales

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos los comandos de compilacion y vinculación completos. Estos se encuentra en las propiedades del proyecto. Me parece que tienes un problema de organización y estructuras  de directorios. Ahora donde t sale el HRESUlT. La ventana no muestra ese error.. No puedes depurar un DLL directamente, solo através de un ejecutable que lo cargue y si lo quieres hacer debes indicar exacta!ente cual es el ejecutable que se inicia. Lo mejor en que en tu proyecto donde generas el ejecutable tengas una referencia a tu proyecto DLL y haces la depuración desde este.